# Most precise type after checking `typeof a === 'object' && a !== null`

Tags: typescript, assert, type-narrowing

I have this assertion function, which checks that the passed value is an object (according to the `typeof` operator), but excluding `null`:

```js
export function assertIsJavaScriptObjectExceptNull(value: unknown) {
    if (typeof value !== 'object' || value === null) {
        throw Error('Value is not an object.');
    }
}
```

I'd like to add an [assertion signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to this function, so that it helps with type narrowing when used. What is the "most correct" type to use here?

```js
export function assertIsJavaScriptObjectExceptNull(value: unknown): asserts value is <type> {
    if (typeof value !== 'object' || value === null) {
        throw Error('Value is not an object.');
    }
}
```

Is it `{[key: string | number | symbol]: unknown}`, or `Record<keyof unknown, unknown>`, or `Object`, or something else?

I'm looking for the type that matches TypeScript's understanding of what this type should be. I know that TypeScript has many settings which can slightly influence this and that JavaScript engines have quirks and bugs that might lead to a result that contradict this understanding. So there might not be a single best answer.

Comment: also `typeof []` returns `"object"` , ie you should also check `!Array.isArray(value)`

Comment: I suggest using something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7zgDw) and as @derpirscher mentioned, you should check if the `value` is an array. Does this approach work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think assertion is useful when you assert to the exact structure that your program care about in the specific use case? Asserting to an object seems doesn't give much extra information to take advantage of.

Comment: @derpirscher I know that arrays are also objects in JavaScript. I intentionally defined `assertIsObject()` the way I did.

Comment: @wonderflame @RickyMo Maybe I did not state the question clearly. My question was not about the definition of `assertIsObject()`, but about its assertion signature. Maybe its name is throwing you off because it contradicts your notion of "object". I will update the question.

Comment: I think the answer is `object`. At least that's what TypeScript is inferring here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4&ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUAPAXI8BrMOAdzAEpEBvAKEVsRmEU0QDIXEoBPABwFM5GGRAF5RiAORwARgCte0ceWp0ViDDVW0A9FsQA9APwbaAXyomgA

Comment: it is. you can see this [post](https://blog.thoughtspile.tech/2023/01/23/typescript-sets/)

Comment: @wonderflame Cool blog post, lots of useful, concise info. Thanks! 

Comment: I suggest then we close the question

Comment: @wonderflame Why? Do you think it does not fit the type of questions that StackOverflow is intended for?

Comment: I can write the answer for sure, just it's pretty small and just about the `object`. If that's fine, I can write

Comment: @wonderflame You do you. Short answers are allowed, if it's understandable and answers the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you looking for is the [object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) type, which represents any non-primitive type. Please, avoid using `Object` which is a JavaScript class and is recommended to be avoided in the official [Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html).

`object` allows us to make sure that the value assigned to a type is not primitive:

```
const noError: {toString(): string} = 1
const withError: object & {toString(): string} = 1;
```

Basically, you can intersect anything with `object` to make sure that the type doesn't allow primitive values.

For a better understanding of the sets theory in the typescript, refer to this [blog post](https://blog.thoughtspile.tech/2023/01/23/typescript-sets/)